# What enterprise shop system should we use?

Tags: ecommerce, shopping

Our requirements for the shop system:

- desktop, tablet, mobile optimized
- multishop functionalities
- each shop has different stocks but same items
- stocks vary by day, e.g. we count 10 items of product A on monday, but 20 items of product A on saturday
- delivery time has time slots (e.g. 10-12, 13-15, 16-18, 19-21)for every day during whole week
- need an interface to SAP finance system
- need an interface to open source PIM (e.g. Akeneo)

Since we do not want use SAP Hybris or something similar, because development is too slow, we decided that it is a system based on PHP. Because there we have enough developers and experience inhouse.

Comment: As far as I know Magento is based on Zend Framework and fulfils almost all of our requirements. Sames does Oxid, but it's only used framework is Smarty Template Engine. Shopeware is too static, I guess, that is why we will not use it.